# How to stop people from downloading my Amazon S3 video files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]I have created a educational website where i'am providing video lectures.
i'am using Amazon S3 bucket for storing/hosting video.
and using the link i'am showing that video to my website but...
That Video has the download button at bottom...
and any one can download the full video
i want to prevent it from downloading
i'am just frustrated

tried changing bucket policies

tried changing ACL's but nothing is working may be i'am wrong

and also tried the aws pre-signed urls but that also has a download button.

please please please..... help me

Comment: Just disable public access to your bucket.

Comment: But if i disable public access to my bucket then no user on my website can access that object

Comment: Develop your  web site to it only streams video content from an Amazon S3 bucket and does not support downloading the video.

Comment: didn't understand bro

Comment: Please post the HTML of your site where you have a download link. It will help community understand exactly your issue.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to have your back-end generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. Your app would first authenticate the user, then generate the pre-signed URL. It will continue to work for a given period of time. After that time, the link no longer works. However, during that time they could download the file.

Another option is to use a **streaming server** (eg Wowza or Elemental) that sends content that can't be downloaded. However, extra costs are involved to run such a service.

Unfortunately, it is the nature of the Internet that you need to send content to users, and users can either consume or download that content. Some people would say that this is a *benefit* of the Internet!

Comment: thank-you john but please tell me solution where video don't have the download button

Comment: Hey John sir i tried S3 pre-signed url but it is still showing the download button what should i do? please help sir

Comment: The download button is a function of how you are displaying the video **within the browser**. The pre-signed URL will be valid for a limited period. If there is a Download button in the browser, they will still be able to download it within that period.

Answer (score 1):

first find the bucket where you keep your files >> go to properties and edit

Default encryption
Enabled
Server-side encryption
Amazon S3-managed keys (SSE-S3)
then save next go to >> permissions and edit the bucket policy

add the condition below: StringLike and Referer

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "PublicRead",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": [
"s3:GetObject"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*",
"Condition": {
"StringLike": {
"aws:Referer": "https: //YOURWEBSITE/*"
}
}
}
]
}

then save

i tested it in my website. it works. it also works in images but it will not affect your pdf documents
if you have any pdf files

Comment: it does not work for the right button click & download option

Comment: It'll not work if video is cached by browser. You'll then be able to download the video